# C# Epplus Save Byte file as XLS in a Desktop Application

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I need to save an ExcelPackage as XLS file. I try to do this and i know how to change content type in a web application but i can't find any solution in a Desktop environment.

Now i am using this code:

```
    using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
    {
       string filename = "OCL_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xls";
       string PathToCSV = "App_Data/OCL/";
       string OCLfolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + PathToCSV;
       string savepath = OCLfolder + "/" + filename;
       System.IO.FileInfo strfilePath = new System.IO.FileInfo(savepath);
       //create a new workbook
       p.Workbook.Properties.Created = DateTime.Now;
       p.Workbook.Properties.Title = filename;
       //create a new worksheet
       p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
       ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
       createExcelData(ws, idCliente, idDestinatario, idSpedDati);
       ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
       for (int col = 1; col <= ws.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
       {
          ws.Column(col).Width = ws.Column(col).Width + 1;
       }
       byte[] bin = p.GetAsByteArray();
       strfilePath.Directory.Create();
       File.WriteAllBytes(savepath, bin);
       return savepath;
   }
```

If i save the file as .xlsx i have no problem but if i save as .xls i have an error before opening the file:

> "The file format differs from the format that the file name extension
>   specifies"

Comment: AFAIK the `EPPlus` library only supports the formats of MS Office 2007 and above, so there is no support for `xls` files, only for `xlsx`. But there are other libraries out there that are able to read/write `xls` files (though the only ones I know of are not free).

Comment: have you tried using `ExcelPackage.Save` method?

Comment: Simply avoid `xls`. It's been replaced over 10 years ago by `xlsx`. The *binary* equivalent to `xlsx` is `xlsb`, not `xls`. The old format, `xls`, is *no longer supported* by the free Google Docs, Sheets or Office 365 offerings. You'll have to use a paid subscription. The reason is that it's *expensive*. It was never well documented in the first place. It actually *requires* Excel for accurate processing.

Comment: *Why* do you want to export data to `xls`? Is it a real requirement? Do you have any customers with unsupported Excel versions, ie before 2007?

Comment: I have a customer with a software that load xls file automatically and don't want to change their software. So i don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client insists on .XLS format and you can't convince them to update to something that's actually supported by MS then I'd suggest you take a look at using [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/), an open-source project for reading/writing files in the older MS Office formats

Comment: I found NPOI to be a very, very poor port of the Java POI project. I couldn't do basic stuff I do easily with EPPlus, and found a few bugs I don't recall details of.

Answer (score 2):

EPPlus does not work with the XLS format. Only XLSX.